# glMultMatrix() not working properly in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have done rendering in two different ways,
first with glTranslate,glRotate etc function which is giving a good output like this,

[image]

After that I wanted to do the same problem using 4X4 Transformation matrix(column-major).I have taken GLdouble array[16],
name of the array is Transformation.

In my case I have computed transformation matrices correctly for 5 objects,one of which is at origin(Identity Matrix).

Whenever I use this in my code before rendering,

```
glMultMatrixd(Transformation);
```

only the first object is getting rendered correctly.The remaining objecting are getting redered flat as given in the picture.

[image]

This is not happening when I remove `glMultMatrix()` function,but all objects getting rendered at origin which is not I want.

--------Edit---AddedCode-------

```
void View::Recur(SceneNode* S,GLdouble (&M)[16]){
    int n=S->getNumChildren();
    glPushMatrix();
    GLdouble Transformation[16]={};
    GLdouble LocalMatrix[16]={};
    GLdouble* Local=S->get_LocalTransform();
    MatrixEquilizer(LocalMatrix,Local);
    MultiplyMatricies(M,LocalMatrix,Transformation);

    glMultMatrixd(Transformation);

    Rendercall(S);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

--------Edit---------------

If add `glLoadIdentity()` before `glMultMatrixd(Transformation)` then it is giving me a more zoomed version of the same,as given in the picture below,

[image]

Comment: Do you use the same transformation matrix for all different objects? 5 different objects should have 5 different poses, expressed by different transformation matrices.

Comment: No sir,I used different transformation matrices for all the 5 objects.I am getting that problem only when I use glMultMatrixd() function.

Comment: depending on your current matrix, `Transformation` is a scaling matrix not a translation matrix.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say, without some code, then. Any calls to `glPushMatrix()` or `glPopMatrix()` missing? If not, try calling `glLoadIdentity()` before `glMultMatrix()`

Comment: Daniel Eberts I have check keeping glLoadIdentity(),it has given me picture like above.

Comment: organicoman could you please explain your answer in little more detail

Comment: where is any `glMatrixMode` call? do you init your matrix with `glLoadIdentity` ?  `glMultMatrix` multiplies the matrix to currently selected matrix, if you multiply on per frame basis without even selecting or initing the matrix first you will get rounding errors pretty quickly and risk to multiply to the wrong stack.... Maybe you want to use `glLoadMatrix` instead ...